# Android Tiles with drawRect

Tags: android, drawrect, tile, ondraw

I want to draw a tile map on a canvas with drawRect() method. The problem is that it only draws the first rectangle on coordinate 0,0. It's suppose to be a 30x20 tile map of the colors red and green. I'm planning to make a snake game.

**Tile.java**

```
public class Tile extends View{

    private final int TILE_SIZE = 16;
    private static int[][] tileMap;
    private static int rows, columns;

    public Tile(Context context) {
        super(context);
        createTilemap();
    }

    public void createTilemap(){
        tileMap = new int[30][20];
        rows = tileMap.length;
        columns = tileMap[1].length;
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                tileMap[i][j] = r.nextInt(2);
            }
        }
    }

    public Tile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint p = new Paint();

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){

                int pos_i = TILE_SIZE * i;
                int pos_j = TILE_SIZE * j;

                switch (tileMap[i][j]){

                    case 0:
                        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        canvas.drawRect(pos_i, pos_j, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, p);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        p.setColor(Color.RED);
                        canvas.drawRect(pos_i, pos_j, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, p);
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<com.example.mohamed.snake.Tile
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawRect(left, top, right, bottom)` will draw *from* left *to* right, *from* top *to* bottom. It will not draw if the difference is `0` or negative.

You're drawing from..

1. `0 to TILE_SIZE`,
2. `TILE_SIZE to TILE_SIZE` (width / height == 0)
3. `2 * TILE_SIZE to TILE_SIZE` (width / height actually becoming negative)
4. ...and so on

You should use

```
canvas.drawRect(pos_i, pos_j, pos_i + TILE_SIZE, pos_j + TILE_SIZE, p);
```

to get the coordinates correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your 2nd for loop. Looks like a copy and paste error. In both `createTilemap` and `onDraw`, change:

```
for (int j = 0; i < columns; i++)
```

to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
```

Also, your arguments to drawRect are wrong. They should be `left,top,right,bottom` not `left,top,width,height`. Try changing your code to this:

```
canvas.drawRect(pos_i, pos_j, pos_i + TILE_SIZE, pos_j + TILE_SIZE, p);
```